# numdifftools vs scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, minimize

I made a loss func that I minimized with scipy.optimize.minimize.
I have 4 constraints, one per parameter.
The model converges and it shows graphically

[image]

Next I used numdifftools to estimate the Hessian and the gradient at my working point (test.refrigeration.params), but somehow my gradient was not the same as for minimize :

```
print(test.refrigeration.solution)
print("\n\nnumdifftools says:")
print(nd.Gradient(test.refrigeration.loss_func)(test.refrigeration.params))
np.diag(nd.Hessdiag(test.refrigeration.loss_func)(test.refrigeration.params))
```

```
 barrier_parameter: 2.048000000000001e-09
 barrier_tolerance: 2.048000000000001e-09
          cg_niter: 222
      cg_stop_cond: 2
            constr: [array([4.1433835e-08]), array([4.94572523]), array([11.74266572]), array([205.95208536])]
       constr_nfev: [705, 705, 705, 705]
       constr_nhev: [0, 0, 0, 0]
       constr_njev: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    constr_penalty: 1.0
  constr_violation: 0.0
    execution_time: 1.0886585712432861
               fun: -1792.2267544952138
              grad: array([ 3.08927155e+01,  6.17049604e-06, -1.84790740e-06,  1.11133536e-06])
               jac: [array([[1., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0., 1., 0., 0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 1.]])]
   lagrangian_grad: array([ 6.75015599e-14,  5.92773968e-06, -1.83442944e-06,  1.11129922e-06])
           message: '`xtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
            method: 'tr_interior_point'
              nfev: 705
              nhev: 0
               nit: 111
             niter: 111
              njev: 0
        optimality: 5.927739681029311e-06
            status: 2
           success: True
         tr_radius: 1.0000000000000005e-09
                 v: [array([-30.89271545]), array([-2.42756355e-07]), array([-1.34779589e-08]), array([-3.61438995e-11])]
                 x: array([4.14338350e-08, 4.94572523e+00, 8.25733428e+00, 2.05952085e+02])


numdifftools says:
[ -6.66111424 -36.09243261  -1.43150895   1.21950988]
array([[1064.99313683, 1078.59848891, -391.34793412,   81.81580485],
       [1078.59848891, 1076.86601335, -392.64416079,   79.45896535],
       [-391.34793412, -392.64416079,  188.84604161,  -39.58414431],
       [  81.81580485,   79.45896535,  -39.58414431,   10.6479105 ]])
```

Why doesn't numdifftools give me the same gradient for the same function at the same point?

Comment: Hi! It is quite difficult to troubleshoot this as your question is put now. You need a bit more focus in the quesiton Can you a) show your loss function b) show the `scipy.optimize.minimize`-call c) skip the plot d) show the constraints e) simplify the code overall as much as possible while still retainning this discrepancy in behavior?

Comment: e.g. skip the print for the hessian, since your question is not about the hessian. that confused me a bit...

Comment: what is `test.refrigeration` ?

Comment: Can you generate a stand alone example that shows this problem with generated data?